# ASP.NET MVC Razor - lambda error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an extension method

```
public static HelperResult List<T> (this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, HelperResult> template) {

            return new HelperResult(writer =>{
                foreach (var item in items)
                    template(item).WriteTo(writer);
            });

        }
```

When I try to use this method like this

```
  <ol>
     @Model.List(t=> {@<li>@t.Title</li>});
  </ol>
```

I get an error **"; expected"**

But if I do

```
<ol>
    @Model.List( @<li>@item.Title</li>)
   </ol>
```

it's OK. (what is the variable "item"? Where does it  define?)

Why does the first example throws an error?

Answer (score 3):

The one solution is to declare razor helper like this

```
@helper ItemWriter(string item)
{
    <li>@item.Title</li>
}
```

And then pass this to your extension function

```
@Model.List(ItemWriter)
```

I know this code can be made better, but this works. Main idea is to use [Razor Helpers](http://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/archive/2010/10/06/declarative-helpers-in-razor.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `@<tagname>...</tagname>` declares a lambda expression that takes a parameter named `item` and returns a `HelperResult`.

You cannot use it as a statement; your first example cannot work.

Comment: For the same reason that you cannot write `x => "abc";` as a normal statement.  There is no way to emit HTML as an embedded statement in Razor; you need to use it as a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much the reason why I had to create Castle.Blade. It supports @=> p ... as an expression to create a lambda with named args. It also supports nesting these declarations, which razor doesn't.